# Suppose that $E[X]^r<\infty$, show that $\int_x^{\infty}|t|^rdP(X\leq t)\rightarrow0$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

**Problem**:Suppose that $E[X]^r<\infty$, show that $\int_x^{\infty}|t|^rdP(X\leq t)\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$

**Attempt** I don't know where to start on the problem. It seems like a obvious result.

Comment: Notice that $\Bbb{E} |X|^r = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |t|^r \, d \Bbb{P}(X \leq t)$. Can you use this to prove the claim?

Comment: @SangchulLee I know this is from the transformation theorem. So we have $\int_0^1|t|^rdP(x\leq t)+\int_1^2|t|^rdP(x\leq t)+\cdots+\int_x^{\infty}|t|^rdP(x\leq t)<\infty$ ? Because this is positive series, so the result follows?

Comment: That is a possible explanation, but you can also come up with a more straightforward argument. Can you begin from the following identity? $$\int_{[x,\infty)} |t|^r \, d\Bbb{P}(X \leq t) = \int_{\Bbb{R}} |t|^r \mathbf{1}_{[x,\infty)}(t) \, d\Bbb{P}(X \leq t) $$

Comment: @SangchulLee So we have $\lim\int_{\mathbb{R}}|t|^r1_{[x,\infty)}(t)dP(X\leq t)=0 $by using DCT?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

For each $x\geqslant0$, we have
$$
\int_{[x,\infty)} |t|^r\ \mathsf dF(t) = \int_{\mathbb R} |t|^r\mathsf 1_{[x,\infty)}(t)\ \mathsf dF(t)\leqslant \int_{\mathbb R} |t|^r\ \mathsf dF(t) = \mathbb E[|X|^r]<\infty,
$$
so by dominated convergence,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb R} |t|^r\mathsf 1_{[x,\infty)}(t)\ \mathsf dF(t) = \int_{\mathbb R}|t|^r\lim_{x\to\infty}\mathsf 1_{[x,\infty)}(t)\ \mathsf dF(t) =0.$$